# No highlight with react-mentions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-mentions` package

When The user select option it **doesn't highlight** it on the view although it appears in the value of the textarea normally, this is example of what the user has seen The word Jack is supposed to display as highlight text (mention):

[image: Picture of what the user has seen]

This is my code snippet:

```js
const list = [
  {
    id: 'jack',
    display: 'Jack',
  },
  {
    id: 'john',
    display: 'john',
  },
]

const TweetField = ({ text, setText }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <MentionsInput
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          style={tweetFieldStyle}
          a11ySuggestionsListLabel="What's happened?"
        >
          <Mention
            trigger='@'
            data={list}
            markup='@[__display__](__id__)'
            renderSuggestion={(user) => {
              console.log(user)
              return (
                <div>
                  {user.display}
                  {user.id}
                </div>
                // <UserListItem {...user} key={user._id} onClick={() => {}} />
              )
            }}
          />
        </MentionsInput>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

And this is the style that applying:

```js
export default {
  input: {
    backgroundColor: '#121212',
    color: '#FFF',
    minHeight: '32px',
    outline: 'none',
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: '6px 6px 0 6px',
    border: `none`,
    fontSize: 18,
    display: 'block',
    lineHeight: 1.5,
  },

  suggestions: {
    list: {
      backgroundColor: '#555',
      border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    item: {
      padding: '5px 15px',
      borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      '&focused': {
        backgroundColor: '#cee4e5',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: The problem might be because of the css. You are overriding input field css. Also looks like you need to add style attribute to Mention tag. You can refer the official guide and example for more details.

Comment: @CodeThing I have already tried this one, Already I have removed the entire style object and everything as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comments, this is happening because your website styling is conflicting with mention styling and you are overriding your input field style with the same color.

Also you need to provide backgroundcolor property to Mention tag as well.
I tried to create my own version of it and looks working fine.
Here is sandbox link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g7mrlt?file=src%2FTweetField.js

[image]

TweetField.js

```
import { MentionsInput, Mention } from 'react-mentions';
import tweetFieldStyle from './tweetFieldStyle';
import mentionStyle from './mentionStyle';

const list = [
  {
    id: 'jack',
    display: 'Jack',
  },
  {
    id: 'john',
    display: 'john',
  },
];

const TweetField = ({ text, setText }) => {
  return (
    <MentionsInput
      value={text}
      style={tweetFieldStyle}
      onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Type here..."
      a11ySuggestionsListLabel="What's happened?"
    >
      <Mention
        trigger="@"
        data={list}
        style={mentionStyle}
        markup="@[__display__](__id__)"
        renderSuggestion={(user) => {
          console.log(user);
          return (
            <div>
              {user.display}
              {user.id}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    </MentionsInput>
  );
};

export default TweetField;
```

tweetFieldStyle.js

```
export default {
  input: {
    color: 'inherit',
    minHeight: '32px',
    outline: 'none',
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: '6px 6px 0 6px',
    border: `none`,
    display: 'block',
  },

  suggestions: {
    list: {
      backgroundColor: '#555',
      border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    item: {
      padding: '5px 15px',
      borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      '&focused': {
        backgroundColor: '#cee4e5',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

mentionStyle.js

```
export default {
  backgroundColor: '#cee4e5',
};
```

Comment: I'm using Material-UI. Also `CssBasline` and `GlobalStyles` component from MUI, something I suspected about it that the component of `MentionsInput` has been added on `Portal` component from MUI

Comment: I tried again with your exact code it's working but slightly different the mark isn't adjust correctly it is slightly down

Comment: Thanks a lot  After your code snippet, the problem was on `line-height` property of the highlighter container I revert it to 1  At the same time the textarea itself was 1.5.